# If I sign someone else's key and later decide it was a bad idea, is it possible to un-sign it?

Tags: pgp, web-of-trust

[Let's say that I sign someone's key and then later decide that was a bad idea](http://xkcd.com/364/) - either it was a bad idea at all, or I should have signed it with a different level of trust. Is it possible, both in a theoretical and also in a practical way, to "un-sign" someone else's key?

Comment: I saw this question and clicked it just to post that XKCD link in the comments, but you beat me to it! :P

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Removing a Local-Only Signature

If the signature is still only kept locally (either by never sending it to anybody or the key servers, or by even having performed an `lsign` which creates signatures that cannot be uploaded), you can actually delete it by running

```
gpg --edit-key [keyid]
[select a uid]
delsig
[go through the assistant for deleting signatures]
save
```

### Revoking Published Signatures

If a signature was already sent to the key servers, you still can delete it locally, but you will not be able to remove anything from the key servers. The OpenPGP key server infrastructure is designed not to delete/forget anything, to be resistant against deletion attacks (where the attacker wants to remove eg. *your* key).

Instead of deleting the signature, now *revoke* it. This time, run

```
gpg --edit-key [keyid]
revsig
[go through the assistant for revoking signatures]
save
```

Now you should upload the revocation certificate (which more or less states "This certificate invalidates the signature I made starting from a given date for the reason given") to the key servers by running `gpg --send-key [key-id]`.

As soon as the revocation sync'd throughout the key servers (some minutes) and other users will update key `[keyid]` (unknown time, possibly rather long), the revoked signature will not be taken into account any more when calculating validity and be displayed as revoked when listing the signatures.

Comment: If the keyserver is commpromised, or no keyserver is used (each person distributes their own key), would it be accurate to say that the revocation may not be integrated in the key if its owner doesn't wish to?

Comment: If you don't trust a key server, choose another one. Lots of them are offered by organizations like universities, linux distributions, ... The key servers are connected to each other, so if everything's fine, everything will be distributed – otherwise, you will be able to realize it isn't by fetching the information from the suspicious key server – unless it's only giving limited information to a limited group of users.

Comment: Tl;dr: use multiple key servers which are probably trustworthy to be somewhat sure.

Comment: The problem (more annoyance) is now you have to give the *new* key to everyone else you still *do* trust. It's better than giving the wrong person your key, which is why I said annoyance.

Comment: Revoking signatures does not change anything regarding keys, especially it does not create new ones. I don't get your point.

Answer (score 11):

You can't unsign, but you can revoke your signature on their key.  Once someone has synced both the original signature and the revocation, their UI should show both and will no longer use the signature in trust calculations.  To do this with GnuPG:

```
gpg --edit-key KEYID
revsig
<Supply a reason>
gpg --send-key KEYID  # Upload key to keyserver, or
gpg --armor --export KEYID  # Manual upload to keyserver
```